# isLocationOnEdge() to split the route

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm a web developer is brazilian, I am doing a service to the routing system for my company, however I am having difficulties in understanding the library's geometry, I would like to know if there is any way for me to know where the route is drawn is Inside of the polygon 1, 2, 3, or 4). This is it for me to make a division of the route, and to trace up to 4 connections. It has a picture of the bottom with the one I already have, along with the code.

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
function renderDirections(result) {
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
}
var triangle1 = [
        {lat: -23.0829, lng: -46.57676},
        {lat: -23.61616, lng: -46.57483},
        {lat: -23.60694, lng: -47.54864}
    ];

 var Triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangle1,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#00FF00',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    Triangle1.setMap(map);
var triangle2 = [
        {lat: -23.0829, lng: -46.57676},
        {lat: -23.61616, lng: -46.57483},
        {lat: -23.61131, lng: -45.67469}
    ];

 var Triangle2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangle2,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#4169E1',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    Triangle2.setMap(map);
var triangle3 = [
        {lat: -23.61131, lng: -45.67469},
        {lat: -23.61616, lng: -46.57483},
        {lat: -24.07554, lng: -46.57185}
    ];

 var Triangle3 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangle3,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FFA500',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    Triangle3.setMap(map);                                
var triangle4 = [
        {lat: -24.07554, lng: -46.57185},
        {lat: -23.60694, lng: -47.54864},
        {lat: -23.61616, lng: -46.57483}
    ];



 var Triangle4 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangle4,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FFFF00',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    Triangle4.setMap(map);

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
function requestDirections() {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: "Rua pedro jose lorenzini",
    destination: "Rua pedro jose lorenzini",
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result) {
    renderDirections(result);
    if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(result, Triangle1) == true) {
     alert("yes");
    }
  });
}
requestDirections(waypts);
requestDirections(waypts2);
```

}

[Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gek7U.png)

Comment: To clarify, you have a polygon, and you want to check if the route is within the bounds of the polygon, correct?

Comment: That's right, I would like to know in which

Comment: So for each point on the route, you want to know which polygon it is in?

Comment: What I really want to do is divide the map into four parts, tracing routes within this polygon and limiting its output, as we make an average of 100 daily deliveries and we cannot let the drivers cross the road. The idea I had is to know if the address belongs to that polygon and thus be able to assemble 4 routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Complete route]
[image: Route one]
[image: Route two]

I got it

First I retrieved the coordinates of the addresses that would be part of the route, I placed each one inside its respective fields, after that I put the function to check if that coordinate belonged to the `polygon`, returning the value `true` it was placed inside the `route array`

```
 function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++){
            if($("#latLgn_"+i).val() != "" || $("#latLgn"+i).val() != undefined){
                temp = $("#latLgn"+i).val()
                temp = temp.split(",")
                temp[0] = temp[0].replace("(","")
                temp[1] = temp[1].replace(")","")
                temp[0] = Number(temp[0])  
                temp [1] = Number(temp[1])
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: temp[0], lng: temp[1]})
                if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, Triangle1) == true) {
                    route.push($("#latLgn"+i).val());
                }else{console.log("Not found")}
            }
        }
        renderDirections(result);
      }
```